# Why is Python's weekday() different from tm_wday in C?

Tags: python, c, datetime

Python documentation defines `datetime.weekday()` as [an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday), while C's `tm.tm_wday` is defined as [days since Sunday](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/). Therefore `tm_wday` is `(datetime.weekday() + 1) % 7`, which is quite inconvenient. Given that Python generally sticks close to C equivalents, why was this made this way?

Comment: FWIW, the standard for the week date encoding ( [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) ) specifies that the weeks starts on monday

Comment: Also FWIW I don't think the datetime module directly wraps the C API functions 1:1. I think it more a a higher level module.

Comment: @JamesMills: But the `time` module *does*, and it uses the same convention (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes of course :) But I don't think you can get to some of the internal C structs? Not unless you use ctypes or cffi.

Comment: I note that the Python `time` module made more changes from the C `struct_tm` conventions. Month numbers are 1 through to 12, not 0 through to 11.

Comment: @JamesMills: why would you need to? Unless you have to interoperate with a C module that expects `struct_tm` values, why not just stick to the Python conventions instead?

Comment: `datetime.isoweekday()` is perhaps more convenient; `struct_tm.tm_wday` is `datetime.isoweekday() % 7`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There was a question here I answered once on your very question "why would you need to?" :) The person in question wanted naonsecond precision which Python just doesn't expose :)

Comment: @dragonroot I honestly think you should withdraw this question :) I don't think you're going to get an answer as to "why"! Who knows why anyone decides to do something! I'm sure there's a "good reason"!

Comment: @JamesMills: As soon as I have some time I was going to dive into the `time` module edit history to see how far back this goes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Serious? You're that bored you want to "spend time digging into Python module source code just to answer a SO question?" :)

Comment: @JamesMills: What makes you think it is boredom that compels me? I am curious as to the answer myself, if there is one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was just kidding :) Go nuts! And post your findings please!

Comment: @JamesMills: Not much to find, really. We'd have to ask Guido; see below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was an explicit decision by Guido van Rossum, when he first created the `time` module for Python version 0.9.9; the [original commit](http://hg.python.org/cpython/diff/6ee380349c84/Modules/timemodule.c) doesn't explain *why* he made this choice, but using 0 meaning Monday has been part of Python from the very moment the `localtime` and `gmtime` functions were added. See the [`time_convert()` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6ee380349c84/Modules/timemodule.c#l257) in that early revision.

We'll have to guess as to why he did this. Most likely, Guido stuck to the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) convention for weekdays instead of the C stdlib convention, perhaps because he's European where [Monday is the prevailing start if the week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-day_week#Week_numbering). Another option is that he patterned the behaviour on another language entirely; Python's roots are various, and apart from ABC, C and C++ also includes Modula 3. Not that the latter uses this convention; it [follows the C stdlib instead](https://modula3.elegosoft.com/cm3/doc/help/gen_html/m3core/src/time/Common/Date.i3.html).

Note that he also used a different range for the `tm_mon` value, from 1 through to 12 instead of the C stdlib convention of using 0 through to 11.

In any case, a [question on comp.lang.python in 2000 about why `time.gmtime()` uses 0 for Monday](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.python/7tjn-g8tocw/50A5gd0fhYEJ) remained unanswered.

Comment: +1 for digging into the revision history of Python's source code base :)

Comment: Might be he also just looked at a calendar on his wall.Weeks starts at Monday in most European countries

Comment: For what it's worth, I find `0` for Monday and `1` for January to be the least surprising convention: we're used to assigning numbers to months, so 1-based index is fine for them, even if it isn't consistent with array indexing in Python. We're not used to assigning numbers to weekdays, so it's fine to use a 0-based index for them.